# STM32F407VTG6 HardFault_Handler

Tags: stm32, stm32cubeide, hard-fault

(note: Using STM32F407VTG, STM32CubeMX for config, FreeRTOS, and tried both IAR and STM32IDE for compilers/debuggers).

This seems to be a common problem, but the solutions I find either aren't clear enough for a semi-beginner, or just don't solve my issue. I am trying to build an automated test jig. It does samples on all sorts of inputs, outputs etc and there are a lot of functions which are run in a sequence, and return either PASS or FAIL (Just a #define PASS 1, #define FAIL 0).

I have some code which was working ok, then as my program grew as I added more and more test routines, it seemed to not work, but only on a return(FAIL). I found that as I returned from some functions, the STM32 would seem to lock up. return(PASS) always works. Doing some debugging I found it was going into HardFault_Handler, which up till now I'd never heard of. After some googling, same faults people were suggesting the stack size wasn't big enough. I was using the default 128 bytes. So I grew it and grew it and grew it right up to max 2048 bytes. No luck.

Some people suggest to look at the stack pointer and program counter, but sadly I have no idea what to actually look at when doing that. Here is a screen capture with a breakpoint set just before I do a return(FAIL).

[image: Before lockup]

This is the after I run the next line.

[image: Before fault]

And finally this is after I enter the HardFault lockup.

[image: HardFault lockup]

Can anyone recommend what I should be looking at to solve this?

Comment: Most likely something in that function trashes the stack. See, the call stack list does not know where to return, and that should only happen on thread main functions.

Comment: Using a debugger, you can examine the stack and find the address that caused the hardfault. As well, the arm has registers that will tell you what it was unhappy about.  A hardfault can be caused by many things - peripheral clock not enabled, peripheral not enabled, accessing illegal address and so on.

Comment: I think overflow happens in your code, I suggest you use "stdint.h" library types for variables and try again.

Comment: Tip: Window -> Show View -> Fault Analyzer

Comment: As mentioned, the stack looks trashed. Use the debugger to check what the stack looks like on entry to `Handset_Test_TA()`. If it's ok, step through the code and see where it is trashed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all your suggestions, and sorry for the delay in getting back to you. Turns out my problem was in

```
void LCD_Write_4_Digit_Number_Decimal(uint16_t Number)  // print 4 digit number on screen
{
    char buffer [4];
    sprintf (buffer, "%4d", Number);
    LCD_Write_Text(buffer); 
}
```

I increased "buffer" to 10 and suddenly I stopped getting the hardfault. I probably need to read up on sprintf a little, I would have thought that a 4 digit number would only need 4 characters to print. Anyway all good now.

Comment: a 4 character string requires 5 bytes to store. Strings in C are NULL-terminated, so you must always leave room for that 0x00 termination.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things which come to mind that can cause such behaviour.

- Somewhere in your code, you are activating an interrupt (may be in a driver call you're making) which occurs at that very moment, coincidentally. Yet, the interrupt has not been setup beforehand correctly (e.g. the entry in the IRQ table for that specific interrupt is missing) and it calls the hard fault handler as a default option
- You have a pointer issue. Somewhere a pointer is used incorrectly and points to your stack. You are effectively modifying your stack and when it's time to jump back to the caller function, the return address in the stack points to an invalid location in memory.

What can you do:

- Go through the driver code and check if there are any interrupts, check if they are setup correctly
- Enable all warnings from your compilation "-Wall" and rebuild the complete project. Observe any warnings you may get. There may be one which indicates a problem with a pointer. It's always good to observe any warnings and correct them immediately - this will solve many errors which occur during runtime. Show us the warnings if you're unsure
- Check if you have explicit casts in your code, those may obscure certain compiler warnings; I'm not saying they are not required but understand that you're telling the compiler that you're doing something (potentially harmful) on purpose